# Internal Server Error 500 angularjs, mvc HttpPost

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I'm updating a row in the database I get this error: http://snag.gy/975mW.jpg

Since it's a 500 error I'm guessing it's something in my C# code giving me this error, the strange thing is that the database gets updated and nothing crashes. So I'm wondering how I could debug this error? I'm sending the data from angular to a web api.

```
 $scope.editUser = function () {
            var user = $scope.selectedUser;
            UserService.editUser(user).success(function (data) {
                console.log('Updated', data)
            }).
            error(function () {
                $scope.error = console.log('Something went wrong')
            });
        }


   [HttpPost]
    public User EditUser([FromBody]EditUserModel model)
    {
        var editedUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == model.UserID);

    editedUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    editedUser.LastName = model.LastName;
    editedUser.Email = model.Email;

    db.SaveChanges();
    return editedUser;
}
```

Comment: You might wanna serialize that editedUser to json if you are returning it to angular.

Comment: Do you see Updated in Console log or something...?

Comment: You could put up a try catch around server side code to see if its not throwing an exception.

Comment: No, the success function doesn't run but console.log ('Something went wrong') gets printed out.

Comment: When I do it like this it never gets to the catch: var editedUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == model.UserID);
            try
            {
               

                editedUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                editedUser.LastName = model.LastName;
                editedUser.Email = model.Email;

                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Error {1}", ex.Message);
            }
            return editedUser;
        }}

Comment: Try returning "JsonResult" instead "User" object. You need to change "return Json(editedUser);"

Comment: I tried that and that gave me "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Result.JsonResult<dbTable>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'" error

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, this is a serialization problem of the return value. Try running the server-side web application under Visual Studio debugger, verify that exception settings are set to to break on all managed exceptions, initiate the action from the browser, and see what happens.

Comment: Hm, that gave me: "A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Self referencing loop detected for property 'table' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Company_7CD5FDAE1E9570C7B1ECAE3417643B51ED95CF06F24DC409AC96D9FE'. Path 'tableName.rowName[0]'". Guess i'll look into that.

Comment: Using google searching for that error gave me some input and i ended up adding             "configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;"
 to my WebApiConfig which i had removed before because it was giving me trouble. Adding that stopped giving me 500 Internal Server Error but the .success function still doesnt run(should say 'Updated'). Edit: after testing a few times, the site eventually crashes saying: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.